# Is it possible to save AdView into memory to move it to another activity?

Tags: android-activity, admob, android-context, adview

So, the main Activity will include an AdView and when user switches to another activity, instead of creating a new AdView, I want to get previously created AdView and add it to current activity's layout.

Is this possible? Setting AdView to a variable inside the mainClass which never dies unless application is exited. (So, adView will be assigned to a variable like it is a static variable)

I am asking this because we create AdView with a Context and if I save AdView variable somewhere else, when the context(activity) it was linked to get destroyed, how could i be able to add it to another Activity with a new context?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do it by creating a Fragment that just contains the AdView and move the Fragment from one Activity to the next.

Remember the AdView is just like any other Android View, it needs to have a Context.

Comment: But i create items in Fragment (AdView for example) with getActivity() context. So, when the first activity gets destroyed, how can i switch fragment's activity? fragment's internals will continue having the first (destroyed) activity's context?